# How to automatically connect to a Twitch stream like a normal user

Tags: python, twitch

I would like to have a program (Python) that can automatically connect to a stream when it launches. It would act and be recognized like a normal viewer, connected with my Twitch account.
I saw the library python-twitch, but it looks more useful for bots (but I may be wrong), and the built-in webbrowser controller, but I think it's too much limited.

I want it to wait for a precise hour (as it always start at nearly the same time), then connect to Twitch with my account and refresh the page until the stream goes on.

Can you help me ?
Thanks

Comment: we could help, if you write some code and post that

Comment: Refresh what page? If you're connecting to twitch programatically via their API there won't be a browser. Might want to take a step back and explain a bit more of the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking into selenium web browsers. It's basically a normal browser window that you can send commands to through Python. I think that's what you're looking for! Check it out at:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Thank you, it looks very complete, I will check it out

Comment: @LoneRetriever No problem! If this solved your problem it'd be great if you click the checkmark by my post (that's how you accept an answer to your question)

Comment: Oh ok, I'm new on this site 

Comment: @LoneRetriever That's ok, we were all new at one point! Just FYI you were downvoted because people on the site do not like broad questions without examples of what you've tried, and what went wrong. They expect you to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example as discussed at: 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Well, I tried something, but there's a problem. I answered my question with what I've tried, is that ok ?

Comment: @LoneRetriever you should make another post with whatever that specific question is. The idea is when somebody has **that** problem they will find **that** post from their google search

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.twitch.tv/overwatchleague")
time.sleep(5)

print("OK")

tab = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/nav[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/button[1]/span[1]")
tab.click()

time.sleep(3)
tab.send_keys("#userName", Keys.TAB)

time.sleep(3)
tab.send_keys("#password")
```

This opens the window to connect to your Twitch account by clicking the button. But it doesn't fill in the text fields, and I don't understand why...